# Array in Objective C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsstring, nsarray

I want to ask about the NSArray in objective C.

I want to create a dynamic array as I don't know about the size of the array. And I also want to insert some of the data to the array. However, I don't know how to decl, init and insert the element in to the array.

The following is the C++ version.
I want to create a empty array A and put all the array element in array B to A.

```
// empty array

string arrA[] = new string();

// put the arrB into arrA

for(int i=0; i < arrB.length(); i++)

      arrA[i] = arrB[i];
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the class named `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`. These are similar to `std::vector` however they are somewhat different in their use due to the way Objective-C works.

```
// Immutable array (must be created with contents specified)
NSArray *strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello", @", world!", nil];

// Mutable array (can be modified)
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];
[strings addObject:@"Hello"];
[strings addObject:@", world!"];
```

The difference with Objective-C `NSArray` objects is that they can take any type of object as long as it is a subclass of `NSObject`.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A string", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1337], [NSDictionary dictionary]];
```

To access values you must use the `objectAtIndex:` message.

```
NSString *aString = [array objectAtIndex:10];
NSLog(aString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `NSMutableArray`. If `arrB` is a `NSArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *arrA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arrA addObjectsFromArray: arrB];
```

Here is the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray:

Comment: Not knocking the answer, but just to point out: You can also just write `NSArray *arrA = [arrB copy]`.

Comment: @Chuck: The question asked for a "dynamic array", and `[arrB copy]` will make another `NSArray` that isn't dynamic.

Comment: I'm not sure what "dynamic" means here that's leading you to protest. All objects in Objective-C dynamically resolve messages and are dynamically typed. If it just means "mutable," then it's `NSMutableArray *arrA = [arrB mutableCopy]`.

Comment: I want to a unknown size of the array when I declare the array. By the way, I would like to ask, what is the different between the 'mutable' and 'dynamic' in objective C mean. Thank you very much.